# int-file:inbound-channel-adapter queue size clarification with AcceptAllFileListFilter filter

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I have question about queue-size config in file inbound channel adapter. Based on my understanding this config allows you to keep no. of file in memory, so higher the number, more memory it will take.

Now we process lots of zip file, each zip file range from few 100kb to mb. Now if I use lower number like(10) and drop 20 zip file to dir, it is only processing 10 and ignoring other 10. What is happening is that we have custom filter which is processing all 20 zips and making an entry in db, so next time poller pick up remaining 10 zip then my filter is rejecting because there is already an entry in to db.

I am now confused how can i avoid this? Is it by changing filter or something else?

Note : we are using Custom filter which is extending AcceptAllFileListFilter as we need to tract duplicates zip file processed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `queue-size` was broken when using any filter - the queue size was ignored.

We recently [fixed that](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2507) in 4.2.

The workaround is to add the logic to your custom filter.